# How can I make the Required attribute for my custom DropDownList editor template operate client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have an editor template for DropDownLists that is marked with an attribute like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DropDownListAttribute : UIHintAttribute
{
    public string SelectListName { get; set; }
    public DropDownListAttribute(string selectListName)
        : base("DropDownList", "MVC", selectListName)
    {
        SelectListName = selectListName;
    }
}
```

And itself looks like this:

```
@using Comair.RI.UI.Core
@{
    var list = this.GetModelSelectList();
    var listWithSelected = new SelectList(list.Items, list.DataValueField, list.DataTextField, Model);
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model, listWithSelected, " - select - ")
```

My issue here is it only validates server side, which is very annoying for a user to resolve all client side validations, only to submit and get a new, surprise server side validation.

Comment: Could you add code of your model

Comment: @SławomirRosiek What is that supposed to mean? This is a general question applies to any model.

Comment: For me it works - did you have problem only with that control or maybe with all client-side validators?

Answer (score 1):

If your client side validation doesn't work it may be caused by one of the following reasons:

1. Your web.config doesn't have that enteries:

   ```
   <appSettings>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
   ```
2. You forgotten to add validation scripts:

   ```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
   ```
3. Your controls are not surrounded by `Html.BeginForm` or `Ajax.BeginForm`
4. Client-side validation can stop working in EditorFor after update to ASP.NET MVC 4 if you use:

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model, listWithSelected, " - select - ")
   ```

   Replacing `Model` with `m` should resolve problem:

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, listWithSelected, " - select - ")
   ```

Comment: All my other client side validation works. My problem is that only my `DropDownList` editor template doesn't validate client side.

Comment: I added another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Set the required class

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model, listWithSelected, " - select - ", new { @class='required' })
```

See [ASP MVC 3: How can I do Client side Validation on a Select List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818862/asp-mvc-3-how-can-i-do-client-side-validation-on-a-select-list)

Comment: Lovely, except the default message is just "This field is required." not the "The {0} field is required." Find if you place validation messages inline, but not so cool if you group them in some 'window' somewhere.